# What does it mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In fact, he only claimed to be the first to coin the term **“vacuum cleaner”** for devices of this nature, which may explain why he is so credited. As we all know, the term **“vacuum”** is an inappropriate name, because there exists no vacuum in a vacuum cleaner.
Rather, (1)**it** is the air moving through a small hole into a closed container, as a result of air being blown out of the container by a fan on the inside. But I suppose a “rapid air movement in a closed container to create suction” cleaner would not sound as scientific or be as handy a name.   Anyway, we are stuck with (2)**it** historically, and it is hard to find any references to “vacuum” prior to Booth.

What does **it** refer to each? 
Really confusing. .

Comment: How does the title of your question related to the content? The content of the question doesn't mention participles or gerunds.  Please [edit] the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rather, **it** (*what was called “vacuum”*) is the air moving through a small hole into a closed container, as a result of air being blown out of the container by a fan on the inside.
>
> Anyway, we are stuck with **it** (*the term “vacuum”*) historically, and it is hard to find any references to “vacuum” prior to Booth.

Comment: Your whole answers was in the quotes. Perhaps it would be clearer to add some explanation beside the quotes.